# How to modify INSPINIA template?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, templates

This question is mostly for those familiar with the template.

I recently purchased INSPINIA template, but because I'm relatively new to templates, I'm having difficulty understanding how to use it; particularly, the blocks within the template's library. For instance, I only want for now, as a test, to have one page with a sign-in form, exactly as it appears in the full version, and nothing else, but simply copying the code from ***login.html*** from ***Angular_Full_Version*** and pasting it into the ***index.html*** in ***Angular_Seed_Project*** between ***<'div ui-view'><'/div'>***
tags doesn't do anything. How do I go about using the elements from the library to create anything? It's my understanding that the template is simply a compilation of reusable blocks, which I can use depending on my needs, correct? It's really just a matter for me to understand how these blocks are utilized.

Is there perhaps a guide that would explain that? I went over their documentation files but that didn't help much.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me some time to figure this out, particularly due to limited previous exposure to AngularJS, but apparently the template is very rich and provides an option to use it under several different scenarios/frameworks (AngularJS, MVC, .NET, static HTML, etc.). For the AngularJS version, the template uses basic ui-routing to switch between the views, or, rather, states. This routing function is not unique to the template but rather to how things are done in AngularJS.  Also, particular blocks can be added to a given state via ng-include. Therefore, long story short, those who want to utilize AngularJS side of the template, should do some digging into the AngularJS framework.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with Inspinia MVC but it is similar to the Angular version. Your approach is correct and it should really work. Try pasting the code outside your ui-view and be sure that the css and js are imported.

Comment: If you keep having problems copy and paste the whole index file and see if that helps